# How to pass QueryStringParams That Include Curly Brackets Into API Gateway Proxy / Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am building a simple redirect server using API Gateway (with required proxy integration) and Lambda.

When I hit the bare endpoint without any parameters, everything works.

When I hit the endpoint with parameters that contain anything BUT curly brackets, everything works.

However, when I hit the endpoint with a parameter such as `?param1={param}` things break.

Checking cloudwatch, I imagine the reason why this happens is because api gateway casts all params to a JSON object, like so:

`queryStringParameters: { param1: '[1]' },`

So, my question is: How could I pass curly brackets in anyway?

I have no option to serialize the url in any way beforehand, and have no way to substitute the curly brackets in the request for something else like -, [, etc...

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: When you say that you have no way to substitute the curly brackets do you also mean that you can't try escaping them?

Comment: @Uberhumus correct!

Comment: Plus one for this, I cant seem to find a limitation on this in the AWS docs either